# Scaler function always returning null

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, null

I wrote this scalar function that returns the price of an item given it's name and category, but when i call it from a select statement it always returns null, this is the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPrice] (@ItemName nvarchar(250), @ItemCatagory nvarchar(250))

RETURNS float

As

BEGIN 
      Return (select top 1 Price from Stock where Item=@ItemName and Store=@ItemCatagory)
END
```

and this is the select statement

```
Select  SNo,ItemName,Category,dbo.GetPrice(ItemName,Category) From Items
```

Comment: Did you check what the query alone returns?

Comment: `top 1` without `order by` is not deterministic. what price should be returned if there are multiple? Though it looks as though that function ought to return something if in fact `WHERE Item=@ItemName and Store=@ItemCatagory` does match something. I wouldn't use a scalar UDF for this anyway for performance reasons.

Comment: did you try executing the select top 1 query by proving proper values ?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is this code:

```
Store=@ItemCatagory
```

In most databases, things called "Store" would not be compared to things called "Category".  Perhaps this should be:

```
Category = @ItemCategory
```

Comment: you are right, but in this particular database store and category are actually the same thing (stupid design I know) but that the way it is, regarding [top 1] I'm trying to get the price of an item, the item is stored in the "Items" table and it's price is in the "Stock" table, the problem is there is nothing linking the two tables , I'm simply trying to avoid getting multiple rows in the result, as I said before stupid DB design